# How to implement a login feature in my android app?

Tags: android, json, api, authentication, httpresponse

In my app I have a json api. The api contains information of various users. I want to build a login feature in my android app so that user can login. I am able to parse the api (the json entity) and getting the HTTPResponse = 200(OK).

But how do I match entered username/password with the ones stored in server? Should it be done on the server side? Or I myself have to do it? Can anyone explain how this is generally done?

Comment: getting all the user details and finding in your end is dedious process. it is better to send the login datas to server and verify there. and you are getting 200 (OK) this is not the data required for parsing. you need to get the entity from the response. go through this link http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: No, I am getting the whole entity also. And if I send the login datas to sever, will they provide any response back? so that I can acknowledge the authentication?

Comment: there should be a json or xml response from the api right? which will hold the response datas. discuss with the api. and see the link that i mentioned.

Comment: I've seen the link, it is not related to login, it just shows how you can parse json api, I've already achieved this, I am getting the parsed data - The response entity. 
My point is the authentication. Will they provide any specific field if user successfully login...for example : "LOGIN_STATUS":"True" ?

Comment: That depends entirely on the API you are using, you'll have to consult the documentation for it.

Comment: Can You Send Me The Api So I can Get Idea....

Comment: see my answer i send some idea

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/) is complete example of login feature in android app using mysql and php webservices.

For implementing login feature in your app following points are important.

1.You need to have Database at server side containing username/password table or sqlite database in your app.

2.You have to implement Web services in order to have interaction between your app and Database.

3.Parsing of the data that you will get in response and displaying it in your app.

I have explained the process in summarized way but you can get many stuffs for it on the web.

You can ask if you have any further queries. :)

Comment: My api is in .net, will this example work on it too?

Comment: Nop bro you have to implement web services in .net then.That example was just the demo of how actually it is implmeneted

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/304302/Calling-Asp-Net-Webservice-ASMX-From-an-Android-Ap - Have a look at this example

Answer (score 0):

You can create this login class and locally store the data in this list.  WHen you login, you can check the value in the list one by one.  If the username is available in the list, it navigates to another screen.  Otherwise, it shows dialogue.

Login class

```
package com.lomza.tut.webview;

public class LogInDataClass {

String UserId,UserName,AuthToken;
}
```

Global class

```
package com.lomza.tut.webview;
import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.List;
public class GlobalData {
 public List<LogInDataClass> LoginListData = new ArrayList<LogInDataClass>();
 }
```

You have to create a `LogInDataClass` object where you parse the response like this.  You also have to add data to the list.

The response is your `JSONObject` object.

```
LogInDataClass LoginData = new LogInDataClass();
LoginData.UserId = response.UserId;
LoginData.UserName = response.UserName;
LoginData.AuthToken= response.AuthToken;
GlobalData.add(LoginData);
okk If You Have any Confusion Than Ask Me
```